# XCode Clang; how to pass custom arguments

Tags: xcode, macos, llvm, llvm-clang

Since Xcode 5, it seems that Apple considers all unknown arguments to clang as errors ([info](https://kaspermunck.github.io/2014/03/fixing-clang-error/)). I wrote some LLVM passes which take some custom arguments. I can't pass them however because of this. Does anyone know if there is a workaround / official way to do this? The method proposed in the link no longer works.

I have an LTO plugin so I pass arguments to it with `-Xlinker -Xlinker -mllvm -Xlinker -argument`. I tried different approaches but can't get Apple clang to accept my argument and pass it on.

Clang -> ld64 -> libLTO.dylib : so I would need a way to bypass Clang checking my argument.

PS. I don't want to ship my own Clang because Apple's takes some extra arguments used by Xcode. I can't build their latest because it still hasn't been open sourced yet! (7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat -Xlinker before each linker argument, example:

```
echo "int main() {}" | clang -x c -flto - -Xlinker -mllvm -Xlinker --print-after-all
```

Comment: Sorry my initial post was wrong, I did in fact repeat `-Xlinker` as I should. I think Apple's `-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future ` no longer works (from my tests).

Comment: It was an error in my buildscripts after all.. Your quick test helped a lot!